# Simplify for loop function in SQL

Tags: postgresql, math

I have translated the following function into PostgreSQL:

```
function probBlock(A,C){
    var invB=1.0;
    var C=Math.floor(C);
    var count=0.0;
    for (k=1;k<=C;k++){
        count++;        
        invB=1.0+(count*invB)/A;
    }   
    var blockProb=1.0/invB;
    return blockProb
}
```

But I need to call this function quite frequently in my code, I hope to simplify such for loop function to reduce its time complexity. When I tried to simplify it in a math way, I found that it may need to involve Gamma function. I don't familiar with Gamma function in a coding way, neither know how to realize it in PostgreSQL.

I know the term `invB` will equal `1+(C-1)/A+(C-1)(C-2)/A^2+...+(C-1)!/A^(C-1))`at the very end of the story, but I can't solve it to a simple `f(A,C)` right now.

So can anyone help me reduce the complexity from `O(n)` to `O(1)` if possible (or reduce as much as possible if impossible to reach `O(1)`) to apply in PostgreSQL?

> More Info:

I mainly call the above function in this following function:

```
function erlangbOfferedLoad(gos,c) {
    var a=c;
    var check=probBlock(a,c);
    while (check>gos) {
        a=a/2;
        check=probBlock(a,c);
    }
    while (check<gos) {
        a=a*2;
        check=probBlock(a,c);
    }
    var fraction=1e-7;
    var step=a;
    var gosCalc=probBlock(a,c);
    var diffError=gos-gosCalc;
    if (diffError<0){
        step=a/2;
        a=a/2;
    }
    while (Math.abs(diffError)>(gos*fraction)){
        step=step*0.75;
        var prevA=a;
        a=a+(step*(diffError>0))-(step*(diffError<0));
        if (a<0){
            a=prevA/2;
        }
        gosCalc=probBlock(a,c);
        diffError=gos-gosCalc;
    }
    return a
}
```

And the reason why I hope to simplify the function `probBlock` is that, for a single run on `erlangbOfferedLoad(gos,c)` in PostgreSQL, it will take me 1 minute, which is totally unacceptable.

Comment: I don't think that you can reduce the complexity to O(1), but if you write an SQL function in C, it will be orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Since the input A and C are both scalars, I just hope to combine that polynomial into one or two elements (like geometric sequence maybe?) so that the complexity can go very close to `O(1)`